# How to write unit test for idb package?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, indexeddb

I am using [idb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb) to use indexeddb in my project. I am trying to write unit tests for a child component which is just a card with a bunch of information, it does not directly interact with the indexeddb, but the parent component does and passes data as props to this child component.While running the unit test for the child component I am getting this error

```
> ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export
> * from './build/index.js';

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

> 1 | import { deleteDB, openDB } from 'idb/with-async-ittr.js';
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you share the code you would like to unit test, and perhaps a section of your unit test?
Also are you able to run other unit tests of say a predictable known function.

Comment: predictable functions run just fine, the error occurs in the render function when I try to render the child component inside its own unit test.